# aux problem compiling latex

Tags: latex, auctex

Exporting latex from org-mode (using `C-c C-e l o`) ".tex" file is fine generated but i can't generate ".pdf" from that.

Same problem even using auctex (`C-c C-c latex`) from ".tex" generated from org.

Here is my output:

```
Running `LaTeX' on `.esett' with ``pdflatex -shell-escape  -file-line-error  --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" .esett.tex''
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(./.esett.tex (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grffile.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wrapfig/wrapfig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/rotating.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ulem/ulem.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.dfu)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/capt-of/capt-of.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
No file .esett.aux.

pdflatex: Not writing to .esett.aux (openout_any = p).
./.esett.tex:27: I can't write on file `.esett.aux'.
\document ...ate \openout \@mainaux \jobname .aux 
                                                  \immediate \write \@mainau...l.27 \begin{document}

(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit; default file extension is `.tex')
Please type another output file name
./.esett.tex:27: Emergency stop.
\document ...ate \openout \@mainaux \jobname .aux 
                                                  \immediate \write \@mainau...l.27 \begin{document}

./.esett.tex:27:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on .esett.log.

TeX Output exited abnormally with code 1 at Sun Jul  8 12:38:16
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an issue with Emacs or AUCTeX.  It is more an issue with the file you want to compile, namely `.esett.tex`.  From [`kpathsea` manual](http://tug.org/texinfohtml/kpathsea.html#Calling-sequence):

> 9. TeX can write output files, via the `\openout` primitive; this opens a security hole vulnerable to Trojan horse attack: an unwitting
>      user could run a TeX program that overwrites, say, `~/.rhosts`.
>      Analogous security holes exist for many other programs. To alleviate
>      this, there is a configuration variable `openout_any`, which selects
>      one of three levels of security. When it is set to ‘a’ (for “any”), no
>      restrictions are imposed. When it is set to ‘r’ (for “restricted”),
>      filenames beginning with ‘.’ are disallowed (except .tex because LaTeX
>      needs it). When it is set to ‘p’ (for “paranoid”) additional
>      restrictions are imposed: an absolute filename must refer to a file in
>      (a subdirectory) of `TEXMFOUTPUT`, and any attempt to go up a
>      directory level is forbidden (that is, paths may not contain a ‘..’
>      component). The paranoid setting is the default.

I suggest you rename your file to `esett.tex` and it should work fine.